# Magento2 - How to add up-sells block in to cart page?

Tags: magento2.3, cart, shopping-cart, up-sells

How to add up-sells block in to cart page for every item?

I have added `in checkout_cart_index.xml`.

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Upsell" name="product.info.upsell" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/items.phtml">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">upsell</argument>
            </arguments>
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\Container" name="upsell.product.addto" as="addto">
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\AddTo\Compare"
                       name="upsell.product.addto.compare" as="compare"
                       template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/addto/compare.phtml"/>
            </block>
        </block>
```

After that I have called this block in to `Magento_Checkout\templates\cart\item\default.phtml` but up-sells product not showing
can any one tell best to display up-sells product in cart page for every item after additional info ?

Comment: Have you mapped up-sell products for the product level from Magento Admin?

Comment: in admin i have added up-sells products it showing in product page but i tried add same code in to cart page not showing

Comment: @ShaileshKatarmal can you tell me